# how to add text below icon in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Selling[icon name="database" class="fa-4x" unprefixed_class=""] Buying [icon name="chevron-down" class="fa-4x" unprefixed_class=""] Mortgage[icon name="suitcase" class="fa-4x" unprefixed_class=""]

Im using the better font awesome plugin,, above is my wordpress text format, I would to place it at the bottom-center of the icon . im pretty new to coding , but I had prior knowledge still.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should include that library : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">`

Then you should select an icon and place the html code at the top.

Ex. Buying `<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in the text tab? This should get you started.

```
<div style="display:flex">
<div style="text-align:center;margin:5px 10px">[icon name="database" class="fa-4x" unprefixed_class=""]<br/>Selling</div>
<div style="text-align:center;margin:5px 10px">[icon name="chevron-down" class="fa-4x" unprefixed_class=""]<br/>Buying</div>
<div style="text-align:center;margin:5px 10px">[icon name="suitcase" class="fa-4x" unprefixed_class=""]<br/>Mortgage</div>
</div>
```

Comment: now how to I like have names for it to incorporate some css names like .icons { position: ect...

Comment: You can put your class names inside the sub divs like so `<div class="icons" style="text-align:center;margin:5px 10px">.....</div>`
Please accept this answer if it answered your original question thanks.

Comment: @johnnn Forgot to tag you.